# how to to make first tab active when I have static tab angularjs UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui

just want to ask if I have static tab with dynamic created tabs. I want to make the first tab of the created  dynamic tabs selected "active" by default. I tried using active but it select last tab 
code

```
<tabset>
<tab active="tab.activate" data-ng-repeat="tab in countytabs" heading="{{tab.countyName}}" data-ng-click="tab.activate = true;activateDepartmentGroupAndSelectButtonSettingForCounty(tab)" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
</tab>
<tab heading="Queue Extensions">
    <div data-ng-include="'/app/reception/QueueExtensions.html'"></div>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: Put active="true" instead of on first tab active="tab.activate"

Comment: @squiroid not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unclear how data is set in your controller, so it's difficult to point to an error as the listed part of the code looks good.

I have simulated the situation in Plunker and my working code looks like:

```
// in the controller
$scope.tabs = [
  { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1', active: true },
  { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2'}
];

// on the view
<tabset>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
    {{tab.content}}
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
</tabset>
```

[Example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8gGJorIx1CTt1NcFRBF?p=preview)